# Lua - if statement with two conditions on the same variable?

Tags: if-statement, lua, coronasdk

How can I set a lower and upper bound value for a variable in a if-statement in lua programming language? I need something like the pseudocode below.

```
if ("100000" >= my_variable <= "80000") then
     do stuff...
end
```

I've tried different formats but my application keeps crashing.

**Update:**

To anyone with the same sort of doubts about lua's syntax, i'd recommend checking the documentation [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/) and keeping it handy. It'll be useful while learning.

Comment: As for your crashing issues, I'm going to assume it just closes straight away? To fix this, you want to open the Lua interpreter and enter `dofile("your_file.lua")`. This will run it in interactive mode, and stop it from closing after the error is shown. (You could also add "pause" to the end of your build script)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should convert your string to a number, if you know for sure that it should be a number, and if there is no reason for it to be a string.

Here's how to do a comparison for a range:

```
myVariable = tonumber(myVariable)

if (100000 >= myVariable and myVariable >= 80000) then
    display.remove(myImage)
end
```

Notice the `and`. Most programming languages don't expand the form `x < y < z` to `x < y AND y < z` automatically, so you must use the logical `and` explicitly. This is because one side is evaluated before the other side, so in left-to-right order it ends up going from `x < y < z` to `true < z` which is an error, whereas in the explicit method, it goes from `x < y AND y < z` to `true AND y < z` to `true AND true`, to `true`.

Comment: I sorry,i forgot to mention that the variable myvalue is a text,so to get the exact numbers stored on the text i must use the quotes!UPDATED THE VALUES.

Comment: @MateusNunes: You should probably convert your text (known as a "string") to a number. See my edit.